# Oracle Java EE-7 tutorial - appclient doesn't execute jar

Tags: java-ee-7

I'm working through the Java EE 7 tutorial, currently in the JMS section. Java EE 7, GlassFish 4, java 7_51, build/deploy using Maven, created admin objects in GlassFish, all looks fine.

I'm trying to run the producer example, so from the command line in the tutorial-root/examples/jms/simple/producer directory I'm running: appclient -client target/producer.jar queue 3

I get no output at all, no exception, nothing, the jar is there, but isn't being executed, as the first line of code would be showing me a system.out and isn't.

I'm missing something here, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was, restarted glassfish, (it had been running for about a week) now it works.